# .Net Publisher Policy: Both Assemblies required to be in the GAC?

Tags: c#, .net, gac

I have created a publisher policy assembly following the post [How to: Create a Publisher Policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz32563a.aspx). The policy redirects assemblies from the version 1.0.0.0 to the version 2.0.0.0.

This does work for me as long as the old assembly (v1.0.0.0) is located on the server (in the GAC). Is it possible to remove the old assembly version from the server?

The configuration I used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
       <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="Assembly.Name"
                           publicKeyToken="d24d3f23b4455982"
                           culture="neutral" />

         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0"
                          newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
       </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Why would you want to remove it?

Comment: Remove what is no longer required? Sort of a mania for cleanliness. It's not absolutely required. I was wondering if it's possible.

Comment: Chicken-and-egg problem, I think.  It can't find the policy file without finding the assembly first.

Comment: @Stefan, so when you remove old assembly it stops working? Strange, if assembly loading process is as Richter describes it in his CLR via C# it should work. But basically you shouldn't remove the old version. For example, that way you can disable publisher policy on per-application basis (by adding `<publisherPolicy apply="no" />` to its config)...

Comment: @Dmitry, thanks for your advice. I'm now double checking the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shame on me. I did a mess with the assembly versions. So the answer is: **Yes**, it works without the legacy assembly.